# создание функции для создания функций Python

Tags: python, функции

МНе нужно сделать функцию для создания функций на Python

Я не знаю как это осуществить, сейчас покажу как я себе это представляю в коде, заранее извиняюсь если этот вопрос оказался глупым

```
def  created():

    created function
```

Нужно сделать одну функцию для создания других функций, с последущим их применением

Comment: вопрос кажется странным. каким образом должны потом создаваться другие функции? что они будут делать? если они однотипные, то смотрите в сторону классов

Answer (score 0):

Пример:

```
def created(text: str):
    def created_fuction():
        print(f'-> {text}')

    return created_fuction


print_foo = created('foo')
print_foo()
# -> foo

print_123 = created('123')
print_123()
# -> 123
```